# creating tree from postfix expression

Tags: c, tree

Here i am trying to create a tree from a given postfix expression.
when i try to execute this first printf statement executes successfully while second one doesn't and the program just hangs up.

```
  mynode *create_tree(char postfix[])
  {
      char symbol;
      int i,k;
      mynode *temp,*stack[100];
      for(i=k=0;(symbol=postfix[i])!='\0';i++)
      {
          temp=(mynode *)malloc(sizeof(mynode));
          temp->data=symbol;
          temp->left=NULL;
          temp->right=NULL;
          //printf("%c",temp->data);
          if(isalnum(symbol))
          {
             stack[k++]=symbol;
          }
          else
          {
              temp->right=stack[--k];
              temp->left=stack[--k];
              //printf("%c %c\n",temp->left->data,temp->right->data);
              stack[k++]=temp;
          }
      }
      return stack[--k];
   }
```

Comment: Please be more specific what you mean by "the program just hangs up." What happens if you run the program under a debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a local array of `mynode` pointers, stored in `stack`:

```
mynode *temp,*stack[100];
```

These are all uninitialized.

You assign `temp->right` and `temp->left` each one of the uninitialized `mynode *`'s,

```
          temp->right=stack[--k];
          temp->left=stack[--k];
```

Then you try to dereference the uninitialized pointer's to get to the `data` element.

```
          //printf("%c %c\n",temp->left->data,temp->right->data);
```

That's why your code dies.